# jQuery nextuntil() with a not

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to jump to the next row in a table, but if it has the class .skiprow then I want to move on to the next one not having that class, AND that is visible.

This doesn't work, but is there a way I can get a .not() or nextUntil(':visible :not(.skiprow)') in there somehow?

```
if( row.next().not('.skiprow').is(':visible') )
{
    var navRow = row.next().not('.skiprow');
}
else
{
    var navRow = row.nextUntil(':visible').not('.skiprow').last().next();
}
var getNext = navRow.children().eq(col).find('.col');
```

EDIT // I think I just solved it:

```
if( row.next().is(':visible') && !row.next().hasClass('skiprow') )
{
    var navRow = row.next();
}
else
{
    var navRow = row.nextUntil(':visible:not(.skiprow)').last().next();
}
var getNext = navRow.children().eq(col).find('.col-data');
```

Please let me know if there is a more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: Can you post an executable code . Look at the link for help https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Can you provide a working example? Some html code and what you expect from it?